# Why is there no universally accepted mathematical definition of turbulence?

Tags: calculus, soft-question

Why is there no universally accepted mathematical equation for the definition of [turbulent flow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbulence)?

Comment: Because nobody has been able to get those solutions?

Comment: I wonder why you think there should there be? After all, "Turbulent" is a relatively phenomenological description. Maybe different underlying micro-patterns, requiring somewhat different mathematical modellings, different equations, can produce phenomenologically similar flows?